# Custom Storage Fields (Not showing in my index)

Tags: 8, search

```
namespace Drupal\custom_storage_example\Entity;

use Drupal\Core\Entity\ContentEntityBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityTypeInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Field\BaseFieldDefinition;

/**
* Defines the Dummy Entity entity.
*
* @ingroup custom_storage_example
*
*
* @ContentEntityType(
*   id = "dummy_entity",
*   label = @Translation("Dummy Entity"),
*   base_table = "dummy_entity",
*   entity_keys = {
*     "id" = "id",
*   },
* )
*
*/
class Dummy extends ContentEntityBase {

/**
* Provides base field definitions for the Dummy Entity type.
*/
public static function baseFieldDefinitions(EntityTypeInterface  $entity_type)
{
$fields['id'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
  ->setLabel(t('Dummy ID'))
  ->setDescription(t('The Dummy Drupal Identifier'))
  ->setReadOnly(TRUE)
  ->setSetting('unsigned',TRUE);

$fields['custom_storage_field'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('integer')
  ->setLabel(t('Custom storage field'))
  ->setCustomStorage(TRUE)
  ->setCardinality(1);

return $fields;
}

}
```

The "problem" here is, should this field (custom_storage_field) appear in the fields to be indexed? Pardon, in advanced if it is a newbie question. :)

[image: My Drupal Test of Custom Storage]